# find strings in data.frame to fill in new column

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I used `dplyr` on my data to create a subset of data like this:

```
dd <- data.frame(ID = c(700689L, 712607L, 712946L, 735907L, 735908L, 735910L, 735911L, 735912L, 735913L, 746929L, 747540L), 
`1` = c("eg", NA, NA, "eg", "eg", NA, NA, NA, NA, "eg", NA), 
`2` = c(NA, NA, NA, "sk", "lk", NA, NA, NA, NA, "eg", NA), 
`3` = c(NA, NA, NA, "sk", "lk", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
`4` = c(NA, NA, NA, "lk", "lk", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
`5` = c(NA, NA, NA, "lk", "lk", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
`6` = c(NA, NA, NA, "lk", "lk", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA))
```

I now want to check every column except ID if it contains certain strings. In this example I want to create 1 column with "1" for every ID that contains a column with "eg" and "0" for the rest. Likewise one more column which tells me if there is either a "sk" or "lk" in the other columns. After that the old columns except ID can be removed from the data.frame

The difficult part for me is doing this with a dynamic number of columns, as my `dplyr`-subset will return different amounts of columns based on the specific case, but I need to check every one that is created in every case. I wanted to use unite first to put all strings together but I will have the same problem then: How can I unite all columns except the first ID one.

If this can be solved within `dplyr` it would be perfect but any working solution is appreciated.

The result should look like this:

```
result <- data.frame(ID = c(700689L, 712607L, 712946L, 735907L, 735908L, 735910L, 735911L, 735912L, 735913L, 746929L, 747540L), 
with_eg = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0), 
with_sk_or_lk = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description, you want one column to check for "eg" and another column to check for both "lk" and "sk". If this is the case, then the following base R method will work.

```
dfNew <- cbind(id=dd[1],
               eg=pmin(rowSums(dd[-1] == "eg", na.rm=TRUE), 1),
               other=pmin(rowSums(dd[-1] == "sk" | dd[-1] == "lk", na.rm=TRUE), 1))
```

Here, the presence of "eg" is checked across the entire data.frame (except the id column) and a logical matrix is returned, `rowSums` adds the TRUE values across the rows, with `na.rm` removing the NAs, then `pmin` takes the minimum of the output of `rowSums` and 1, so that any elements with 2 are replaced by 1 and any values with 0 are preserved.

This same logic is applied to the construction of the "other" variable, except the presence of either "lk" or "sk" are checked in the initial logical matrix. Finally, `data.frame` returns a 3 column data.frame with the desired values.

This returns

```
dfNew
       ID eg other
1  700689  1     0
2  712607  0     0
3  712946  0     0
4  735907  1     1
5  735908  1     1
6  735910  0     0
7  735911  0     0
8  735912  0     0
9  735913  0     0
10 746929  1     0
11 747540  0     0
```

Comment: Maybe even simpler:
`x = dd[-1]=='eg' ; cbind(dd[1], 1*!!rowSums(x,na.rm=T), 1*!!rowSums(!x,na.rm=T))`

Comment: Nice. Using `1* !!` to convert integers to binary (0, 1) is pretty cool.

Comment: or `+!!` but it's not very explicit.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an admittedly hacky dplyr/purrr solution. Given that your IDs don't seem like they'll ever equal 'eg', 'sk', or 'lk', I haven't included anything to not search the ID column.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
dd %>% 
    split(.$ID) %>% 
    map_df(~ data_frame(
        ID = .x$ID, 
        eg = ifelse(any(.x == 'eg', na.rm = TRUE), 1, 0), 
        other = ifelse(any(.x == 'lk' | .x == 'sk', na.rm = TRUE), 1, 0)
    ))
```